# The loop repeats adding characters "!?.," even though it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, character, console.log

I wanted to create a simple function that turns a sentence into NATO phonetic alphabet. The loop works fine for the alphabet but creates a strange character problem. My code:

```js
const alphabet = ["Alfa", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel", "India", 
"Juliett", "Kilo", "Lima", "Mike", "November", "Oscar", "Papa", "Quebec", "Romeo", "Sierra", "Tango", 
"Uniform", "Victor", "Whiskey", "Xray", "Yankee", "Zulu"];

function phoneticAlph(words) {
let translatedTxt = "";
for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < alphabet.length; x++) {
        if (words[i].toUpperCase() === alphabet[x][0]) {
            translatedTxt += `${alphabet[x]} `;
        } else if (words[i] === "!" || words[i] === "?" || words[i] === "," || words[i] === ".") {
            translatedTxt += words[i];
        }
     }
 }
 console.log(translatedTxt)
}

phoneticAlph("!I.a,m!Robot")
```

This appears in the console:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!India ..........................Alfa ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,Mike 
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!Romeo Oscar Bravo Oscar Tango
```

I completely don't understand what happened or how to fix it to display the characters correctly. I will be very grateful for your help and for explaining what actually happened.

Comment: Everything that is *not* a letter is repeated 26 times because it falls in the `else if` which is inside the loop over the phonetic alphabet. So, you get one symbol repeated for each phonetic item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that that break statements are missing in the second loop, which means that even though one of the if statements is true, the loop continuous. Try to add break statements inside your if statements, in order to stop the loop when you find what you are looking for inside the alphabet array.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the else if inside the second for cycle. For each special characters the first if is always skipped ,instead the else if is always hitted. Move the else if part outside of the second cycle for.

```js
const alphabet = ["Alfa", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel", "India", 
"Juliett", "Kilo", "Lima", "Mike", "November", "Oscar", "Papa", "Quebec", "Romeo", "Sierra", "Tango", 
"Uniform", "Victor", "Whiskey", "Xray", "Yankee", "Zulu"];

function phoneticAlph(words) {
let translatedTxt = "";
for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < alphabet.length; x++) {
        if (words[i].toUpperCase() === alphabet[x][0]) {
            translatedTxt += `${alphabet[x]} `;
        }
     }
     if (words[i] === "!" || words[i] === "?" || words[i] === "," || words[i] === ".") {
        translatedTxt += `${words[i]} ` ;
    }
 }
 console.log(translatedTxt)
}

phoneticAlph("!I.a,m!Robot")
```

Comment: You're right, the continue isn't neccesary, but it makes sence not looking further...

Answer (score 1):

You can continue with the outer loop on a hit, and the else case must be moved in the outer loop:

```js
    const alphabet = ["Alfa", "Bravo", "Charlie", "Delta", "Echo", "Foxtrot", "Golf", "Hotel", "India", 
    "Juliett", "Kilo", "Lima", "Mike", "November", "Oscar", "Papa", "Quebec", "Romeo", "Sierra", "Tango", 
    "Uniform", "Victor", "Whiskey", "Xray", "Yankee", "Zulu"];

    function phoneticAlph(words) {
    let translatedTxt = "";
    outer: for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < alphabet.length; x++) {
            if (words[i].toUpperCase() === alphabet[x][0]) {
                translatedTxt += `${alphabet[x]} `;
                continue outer;
            }
         }
         if (words[i] === "!" || words[i] === "?" || words[i] === "," || words[i] === ".") {
                translatedTxt += words[i];
         }
     }
     console.log(translatedTxt)
    }

    phoneticAlph("!I.a,m!Robot")
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm new to javaScript.but I think I fixed the problem.First, you must remove "words" from characters other than letters. the next codes are still the same.

```
 function phoneticAlph(words) {
 let translatedTxt = "";
 let cleanWords=words.match(/\w/g);              //only letters
 for (let i = 0; i < cleanWords.length; i++) {
   for (let x = 0; x < alphabet.length; x++) {
    if (cleanWords[i].toUpperCase() === alphabet[x][0]) {
        translatedTxt += `${alphabet[x]} `;
    } else if (cleanWords[i] === "!" || cleanWords[i] === "?" || cleanWords[i] === "," 
  || cleanWords[i] === ".") {
        translatedTxt += words[i];
      }
    }
   }
  console.log(translatedTxt)
  }

      phoneticAlph("!I.a,m!Robot")
```